# Laravel Login with remember me

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, remember-me

I have some problems with "remember me". It keeps me logged in even if I haven't checked the "remember me" box.

This is my code - `LoginController.php`:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')], $request->has('remember'))) {
        return redirect('/');
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('error', 'The email or password is incorrect.');
    }
}
```

`login.blade.php`:

```
                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('error'))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            {{ session('error') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">{{ __('Email') }}</label>
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                            <label for="remember">{{ __('Remember Me') }}</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Login') }}</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></p>
                        </div>
```

My database has a column called `remember_token` which should help with the "remember me".

Comment: Laravel will keep your session for 60 minutes ideally if you do not logut. But you can modify this time according to your need.

Comment: Make sure the value of $request->has('remember') is either true or false, depending on the chosen option.

Comment: Laravel uses both cookies and browser/PHP sessions to keep the user logged in. The sessions will expire depending on your Laravel and server settings. If you want them to be logged out on browser, close, you'll need to use javascript to trigger the logout process on close (which can be tricky) or make the session time shorter

Answer (score 0):

Remember me does not affect the user's identity. Identification takes place directly through the e-mail password or username.

It seems to me you want if the checkbox is not checked the user should not be authorized, but it is not true.

Comment: I want to be logged out after closing the browser, if the checkbox is not checked